# Some keys don't appear in xev

Tags: xorg, kubuntu

I can't change my screen brightness by pressing brightness keys on the keyboard, but they change through `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`. So I started to diagnose the issue. I ran `xev`, and I'm trying to see what happens when I press `Fn+F5` or `Fn+F6`, which are brightness controls, and xev didn't show anything. I must note that it notifies my when I press volume controls, for example.
are `F5` and `F6` keys working? yes, but not when I press them with `Fn` key.
do I have any entry in `xmodmap` for brightness? yes:
     `keycode 232 = XF86MonBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessDown

     keycode 233 = XF86MonBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessUp`

What's happening, and what should I do to correct it?
I'm using vaio S series laptop with kubuntu precise on it.

Comment: Do you have `xkeycaps` installed? With that you could set the correct layout so that the `Fn` key is recognized.

Comment: the `Fn` key is recognized very well, i can use it to change volume, for example. the problem is with combination of `Fn+F5`

Comment: You don't happen to be talking about a Zenbook do you? Either way I think the answer might be that the acpi driver does not support those keys yet, either that or we're not using the right one.

Comment: I've reported a bug: http://dev.iksaif.net/issues/248

Comment: no, i'm using a vaio `vpcs136fg` machine; so i think the place that you've reported the bug to is irrelevant. yet i appreciate your attention ;)

Comment: @JamieKitson What makes you think that this is a bug?

Answer (score 3):

You can start by researching the drivers which are used for your ACPI keys and 
finding instructions on how to configure your ACPI daemon. The chances 
are your laptop is supported in the kernel (linux), so making things work is a 
matter of loading the correct module (**modprode sony_laptop**).

from menuconfig in /use/src/linux:

```
 CONFIG_SONY_LAPTOP:                                                            
  │ This mini-driver drives the SNC and SPIC devices present in the ACPI      
  │ BIOS of the Sony Vaio laptops.                                            
  │ It gives access to some extra laptop functionalities like Bluetooth,      
  │ screen brightness control, Fn keys and allows powering on/off some        
  │ devices.                                                                  
  │ Read <file:Documentation/laptops/sony-laptop.txt> for more information.
```

For example, on my EEE PC I have a module called *eeepc_laptop* 
(CONFIG_EEEPC_LAPTOP in /usr/src/linux/.config) which is responsible for handling  the power-management
features and the *Fn-keys*:

```
$ lsmod  | grep eee
eeepc_laptop           12682  0 
sparse_keymap           2733  1 eeepc_laptop
```

The acpi-events generated by the keys can be monitored (to verify that they 
are working) by running **acpi_listen** and pressing a few *Fn-keys*.

```
$ acpi_listen 
hotkey ATKD 0000002f 00000078
hotkey ATKD 0000002e 00000003
```

On my system, the [acpi daemon](http://tedfelix.com/linux/acpid-netlink.html) detects such events with scripts in **/etc/acpi/events/** and scripts
in **/etc/acpi/actions/** do certain things when the events are detected. I'm only saying 
this to give you a sense of orientation. Chances are your distribution ships with a 
well configured ACPI daemon (maybe not the same as mine). Again, check their Wiki or Handbook.